# Maximum Field Reached for Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

Is there a way on how to increase the number of fields in Database Access 2007?

Here's my problem:

I have to create the top level data wherein the user need to define the end product.

```
Example: Car Model X
```

Then I created a project with 4 sections to list the cost in building this Car. Example:

```
Section 1: Raw Material 
     - lists raw materials to build 1 car where scrap percentage is included.
Section 2: Molding Process 
     - lists equipment cost in Molding Process to build 1 car
Section 3: Assembly Process 
     - lists equipment cost in Assembly Process to build 1 car
Section 4: Purchased Items 
     - list purchased materials to build 1 car
```

Each section should contain 20 identical items. Example

```
Section 1: > Raw Material 1
1. Component Part #,
2. Component Description,
3. Qty,
4. Material Part #, 
5. Material Description,
6. Material Usage,
7. Unit Price,
8. Scrap Rate, etc.
```

I will repeat these items 20X in the table.

I design it that way because I want everything to be seen in a report from section 1 to 4.

There are 20 identical items each section in case there are 20 raw materials/purchased materials/processes to build a car.

I edited this post to add:

This is related to the maximum number of locks for a single file.

I already reached around 773 columns.

```
Table 1 - 179 fields
Table 2 - 221
Table 3 - 221
Table 4 - 121
Table 5 - 7
Table 6 - 11
Table 7 - 8
Table 8 - 3
Table 9 - 1
Table 10 - 1
```

Help says that in order to increase the locks, I have to increase the registry for my computer. If I do that what will happen? Will the database work to other users if they use other computer?

Thanks,

Michael

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should look at your table design? For example, you say you have twenty fields in each of four sections and these fields are repeated. It is nearly always a sign that the design should be re-evaluated if anything is repeated. First get the database design right and then consider how to output the data.

**Section 1: > Raw Material 1**

```
Component Part #,
Component Description,
Qty,
Material Part #,
```

However, there are a number of advantages in seeing all these as a flat table. I will assign somewhat random names to the tables and fields, because it is not quite clear what your project is about, so very roughly:

**Inputs Table**

```
ID --> Primary key
Input
```

Data

```
ID  Input
1   Raw materia
2   Whatever
```

**Inputs details table**

```
ID --> Primary key
InputID --> Foreign key
Detail
```

Data

```
ID  InputID   Detail
1      1      Component Part #,
2      1      Component Description,
3      1      Qty,
4      1      Material Part #,
```

Depending on how the project works, the input detail table might be a lookup with just one line for each possible detail. This would then mean a third table where the user selected details from the detail table to create the project table.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear. I just uploaded an excel file in 4shared. Hope this will explain my project. Here is the link.  
http://www.4shared.com/file/ZumahfKb/Project.html  
I still can't use the above design because I need to show the 20 items for each section when user choose a product.  
The columns per section is not just 4 fields. They're for example only

Answer (score 0):

Remou is correct, to restate you need one table for Product

```
Product (ProductId, Productname ....)
```

and one table for the product components that make up each section say ProductComponent.

```
ProductComponent (ID, ProductId, SectionName, Part_Equip_No, Description, Qty, Scrap)
```

Have a form where the user selects the product and a subform that displays the ProductComponents for that Product sorted by SectionName

Comment: @Remou and Chris Thanks to you both. If I will create Product Component tables (for each section such as Product Component section A, B, C, and D), do I need to make relationship (one-Product to many-ProductComponent) for each table? If I'll do that, the report will be blank if I'll put the Product table's fields + 4 ProductComponent tables' fields. This is only good if two tables are added in a form or report.

Comment: Remou gave me another idea to use DLookup. I just need to setup an unbound combo box field to list ProductID. After selecting one ProductID, section A-D will be lookup in unbound fields. My question now is "What will be the problems that I will be facing if I'll use too many Dlookup in a report/ form to load 20 records (with 5-10 columns) each section?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I also setup the database where the user needs to define a-t for every record he will create for each section. If he chooses a, the form will output product+letter (say 1234a, 1234b... 1234t). I will DLookup this code in a report/form when user type the ProductID. NOTE: '1234' is the ProductID.

Comment: I also added IIFfunction in each unbound field. Example: =IIF(ProductID_Unbound_Field<>"",DLookup("Part_Equip_No","ProductComponentA_tabl‌​e","ProductID_Unbound_Field & 'a' = Code"). The Code will be the ProductID+letter that I mentioned above. I will create  tons of DLookup for each sections. What do you think?